# autocomplete/intelliSense not working for golang in vscode

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I tried below things

1. Restart of VSCode
2. Uninstalled and installed Go plugin from google team for VSCode
3. Ran gopls server in code repo using `go get golang.org/x/tools/gopls@latest`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I was able to solve this problem. My project was required `export CGO_LDFLAGS_ALLOW=".*"` env var to be set.

So, I added below section to the settings.json of the Go plugin for vscode

```
 "go.toolsEnvVars": {        
    "CGO_LDFLAGS_ALLOW":".*"
 }
```

After that, all the modules were loaded successfully and VSCode was able to provide intelliSense.

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes vscode do not detect the `GOPATH` and `GOROOT`, try to set them manualy in the user settings (JSON) like so :

```
  "go.gopath": "..path..",
  "go.goroot": "..path..",
```